# JS DOM | Selecting ALL children of DOM element

Tags: javascript, events, dom, dom-events

I created a date-picker in JS. When an input with a specified class is clicked, the date-picker is triggered.

When I click OUT of the input or the date-picker, it hides.

**The problem:**

- When I click ON the date-picker, it hides because I am not clicking the date-picker itself, but one of its many children.

**I tried:**

- To add OR condition to the IF statement (see bellow);
- To select all child nodes of date-picker with "date_picker.childNodes" but it only selects the two first children.

**What I want:**

- Select all DIV elements of date-picker ; so when when ever I click on it, it show still shows the date-picker. How to? (If you have any other solution, I'll take it).

Date-picker:

```
<div class="date-picker">
    <div class="date-picker-header">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="date-picker-body">
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
        <div class="child"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS triggering the date-picker:

```
var date_picker = document.querySelector(".date-picker");
var input = document.querySelector(".input-date-picker");

document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {

    // If the INPUT or the DATE_PICKER or any of its children is clicked.
    if(e.target == input || e.target == date_picker || /* date_picker children */) {
        // Triggers the date-picker.
    }
    else {
        // Hides the date-picker.
    }

}, false);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if calling `closest('.date-picker')` on the `target` returns the datepicker element - if so, the clicked element is either the datepicker or one of its children:

```
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(e) {
    // If the INPUT or the DATE_PICKER or any of its children is clicked.
    if(e.target === input || e.target.closest('.date-picker')) {
        // Triggers the date-picker.
    }
    else {
        // Hides the date-picker.
    }
});
```

Feel free to leave out the third `false` parameter if you want, capturing defaults to `false` anyway.

Comment: Wow, I didn't know about this function. It worked perfectly. Thank you very much. PS: Took the `false` thing in note.